# CakePHP app in directory breaks redirects done with query string

Tags: php, cakephp

My **CakePHP 2.0** application url is: `http://localhost/testapplication/`

and when I do redirects on a login from a link I use a query string e.g.

`localhost/testapplication/login?continue=/testapplication/admin/posts`

The redirect is done using:

```
            if(isset($this->params['url']['continue']))
            {
                $pathtoredirect = $this->params['url']['continue'];
            }
            else
            {
                $pathtoredirect = $this->Auth->redirect();
            }

            return $this->redirect($pathtoredirect);
```

However when I do the redirect I will end up at a URL like:

`localhost/testapplication/testapplication/admin/posts`

As you can see it redirects to the passed url but because the passed url also contained the base directory it duplicates it breaking the url redirect and ending up at a 404!

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

**Just to confirm:**

- The url does start with a `/` so it does redirect at the root level, but the problem is that root level is a directory so it duplicates it as it's also passed in the query

Comment: which part of the conditional is causing the problem true, false  or both, I presume `true`? Also when you assign `$pathtoredirect` does it still start with a `/`?

Comment: Yes the true part when using then continue value. The path is exactly as you see in the OP.

Comment: Hi so what is the value of `$this->params['url']['continue']` is it this '/application/application/admin/posts' or '/application/admin/posts' but I have a feeling it may be 'application/admin/posts'

Comment: Are you using Cake's Auth Component? It's supposed to automatically take care of this kind of thing (login redirection).

Answer (score 1):

If you construct a path in either of the following ways:

```
$continue = Router::url(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'posts'));
$continue = Router::url('/admin/posts');
```

then `Router::url` will prepend the base path `/application`. Then if you call `Router::url` again on the resulting url (or `redirect` to it) `Router::url` will prepend it again. That's the way it works, and there's nothing you can do about it.

In reality, the url `/application/admin/posts` is ambiguous, but CakePHP reads it as `controller=application`, `action=admin`, and the first argument is `posts`.

#### The only ways to circumvent this are:

Use an absolute url:

```
$continue = Router::url(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'posts'), true);
```

Or make sure `Router::url` is only called once, e.g.:

```
$continue = '/admin/posts';
```

Or after login

```
$pathtoredirect = FULL_BASE_URL . $this->params['url']['continue'];
```

Comment: /application is the name of the app and not a controller! The issue is being caused because I get the redirect URL which contains the base path but cake adds this to the current app base hence the duplication.

Comment: `$pathtoredirect = FULL_BASE_URL . $this->params['url']['continue'];` is basically what Cake is doing already! But that's the problem as FULL_BASE_URL would have `/application` as that is the base of the application url. But my query also contains it!

Comment: I know /application is the name of the app, but CakePHP assumes it's the name of the controller. Bottom line is, as I wrote, you can't apply Router::url twice if you have a base path, unless you generate a full (absolute) url the first time. Furthermore, FULL_BASE_URL is   `http[s]://env('HTTP_HOST')`, doesn't contain `/application`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a couple options here. If `$this->params['url']['continue']` is exactly what you pass in with your query string, is it possible for you to modify your query string so it is just `/admin/posts` so the complete URL will be `application/admin/posts`?

You may not have to do this, but I'd need to see exactly what `$this->params['url']['continue']` looks like. Please do a `die(debug($this->params['url']['continue']));` somewhere before your redirect so we can investigate further.

Comment: It is JUST: `/application/admin/posts`

Answer (score 0):

Okay the fix was to do the following:

Get the full URL (as mentioned by others) here using a helper:

```
class LinkHelper extends AppHelper
{
    public function selfURL()
    {
        $pageURL = 'http';

        //if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')
        {
            $pageURL .= "s";
        }
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
        {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } 
        else
        {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }

        $pageURL = urlencode($pageURL);

        return $pageURL;  
    }

}
```

Then when using the URLs making sure to encode and decode them for use in the address bar

e.g. `$pathtoredirect = urldecode($this->params['url']['continue']);`